# How paste be used as a message with R stopifnot?

Tags: r, error-handling

I want to report a message that is dependent on variables using `stopifnot`. With the normal syntax using `paste` instead of a verbatim character string it gives an error. Is it possible to do this?

```
# As expected
stopifnot("a msg" = NULL)

# Fails
stopifnot(paste("a", "a msg") = NULL)

# Fails
msg = paste("a", "a msg")
stopifnot(msg = NULL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use `do.call` and a named list of evaluated expressions:

   ```r
   do.call(stopifnot, setNames(list(1 == 1, 1 == 2), paste("msg", c("A", "B"))))
   # Error: msg B
   ```
2. Don't use the named-expression, handling it directly:

   ```r
   if (!isTRUE(1 == 2)) stop("msg B", call. = FALSE)
   # Error: msg B
   ```

   (Though I suspect you are trying to stick with `stopifnot`'s named convenience.)